# Passing just the enum value in a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, enums, parameter-passing

I have an enum called SemverPartOption which has the following values:

```
public enum SemverPartOption
{
    Full,
    Version,
    Major,
    Minor,
    Patch,
    Micro,
    Pre,
    Meta
}
```

and then I have a method which uses this enum as a parameter:

```
public static string SemverPart(SemverPartOption? Option = SemverPartOption.Full)
```

Both the enum and the method live in `AppName.Helpers` namespace and the `AppInfo` class.  I am trying to be able to call the method and just pass the enum value.  Example:

What I am having to do:

```
Helpers.AppInfo.SemverPart(Helpers.AppInfo.SemverPartOption.Major);
```

What I would be ok with:

```
Helpers.AppInfo.SemverPart(Major);
```

**MOST IDEAL:**

```
SemverPart(Major);
```

Is there a way to do this without constantly having to use a `using` statement?

To be clear I don't want to have to use a `using` statement because I would like to call this method in several Razor views belonging to different controller classes.

Comment: Are there naming collisions? e.g. Do other (already included) namespaces have a method/enum matching those names where a fully-qualified name would be required?

Comment: No the enum and the method are the only of their kind in the Application.

Comment: I think you cannot use `Major` Directly without using `SemverPartOption.Major`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll have to add the `using` statement.

This shouldn't be a problem; your IDE will give you the option to just import it when you type `Major` instead of having to manually add it.

If you have another enum/class with the same name (`Major`) then it will act up but you can get past this by adding more information (like `SemverPartOption.Major` or however much you have to go up), or by using [an alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

In order to import this enum into every one of your razor views, go to your /Views/Web.config file and add (or adjust) the following XML:

```xml
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host
      factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="AppName.Helpers.AppInfo" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: It does and I can put it in manually, the problem is I would like to be able to call this method in several Razor views, not all of which live in the same Controller class.

Comment: Could this not be placed in some Global namespace?

Comment: @aaronmallen: you can add a "global" `using` statement in your Views/Web.config file so you don't have to explicitly define it in every view. Is that what you'd like?

Comment: If you're using it in Razor, you can have a look at `~/Views/web.config` and add an entry to `configuration/system.web.webPages.razor/pages/namespaces` node (like adding a `using` in a code file)

Comment: I was unclear and that is my fault, `AppInfo` is a class not a namespace.  Which is fine I'm just having to call `AppInfo.SemverPart` the problem is I am still having to call `AppInfo.SemverPartOption` to declare the `enum` value. My goal is to at the least be able to call `AppInfo.SemverPart(Major)` instead of `AppInfo.SemverPart(AppInfo.SemverPartOption.Major)`

Comment: Is the Enum within the class? Or assigned side-by-side?

Comment: So define the enum outside the class.

Comment: Defining the enum outside the class still requires `AppInfo.SemverPart(SemverPartOption.Major)`

Comment: Yes, and you will not be able to get around that. I believe in Java an enum is translated by the compiler to a public static field in the class; something you can't specify as just the field. Assuming C# does the same behind the scenes, you'll always have to specify the type as well.

Comment: And the fruits of your assistance: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52519/return-custom-assembly-attribute-variables

Answer (score 1):

Given the additional information (about this being used in a razor page) you can add a "using" to razor using the `~/Views/web.config` file. The node would be as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Web" />
        <add namespace="AppName.Helpers.AppInfo" /> <!-- new addition -->
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

This is the facsimile of adding `using AppName.Helpers.AppInfo` to a code file, but applies specifically to @Razor pages.

Comment: See comments on Jeroen Vannevel's answer as well as edit to the question.